# Curl trying to get contents but capturing load page

Tags: curl, wget

help

https://workflowy.com/s/CbqM.M3tcZFhqd3#/?q=ADM-NF01

I am trying to capture

Feature Roadmap
V0 - Alpha
Basic A11Y and I18N
Foundations for Accessibility and Internationalisation
ADM-NF01

But all I seem to be capturing is The Loading screen

Capture=`time (curl -s -G -L --connect-timeout 100 https://workflowy.com/s/CbqM.M3tcZFhqd3#/?q=ADM-NF01)`

Only really interested in this line V0 - Alpha to capture this can change (versioning) I'll cross that bridge when i get this bit working.

is there a way to do this tried curl and wget but no luck

main goal is to search for ie ADM-NF01 and grab V0 - Alpha

here are some examples
https://workflowy.com/s/CbqM.M3tcZFhqd3#/?q=DV-F85
DV-F85 = Vn - Future

https://workflowy.com/s/CbqM.M3tcZFhqd3#/?q=ADM-F71.1
ADM-F71.1 = V1 - Beta

I have no idea where to start tied googling someone suggested JSON parsing but know idea how to do that as i cant even get to data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the network log, you have the JSON content available at :

https://workflowy.com/get_initialization_data?share_id=CbqM.M3tcZFhqd3&client_version=18

which you can parse with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) JSON parser to apply filter on a specific field and get the intended output :

```sh
filter="ADM-NF01"

curl -s "https://workflowy.com/get_initialization_data?share_id=CbqM.M3tcZFhqd3&client_version=18" | \
jq -r --arg filter $filter '.projectTreeData.mainProjectTreeInfo | 
       .rootProject.nm as $h1 | 
       .rootProjectChildren[] | 
       .nm as $h2 | 
       .ch[] | 
       .nm as $h3 | .no as $h4 | 
       select(.ch != null) |
       .ch[] | select(.nm == $filter) | $h1,$h2,$h3,$h4,.nm'
```

which gives :

```
Feature Roadmap
V0 - Alpha
Basic A11Y and I18N
Foundations for Accessibility and Internationalisation
ADM-NF01
```

For the jq part :

- `--arg` is used to pass the filter value
- the fields you want to keep are stored in variables with `as $var`
- `select` is used to apply the filter

> main goal is to search for ie ADM-NF01 and grab V0 - Alpha

If you just need the `V0 - Alpha` part :

```sh
filter="ADM-NF01"

data=$(curl -s "https://workflowy.com/get_initialization_data?share_id=CbqM.M3tcZFhqd3&client_version=18" | \
jq -r --arg filter $filter '.projectTreeData.mainProjectTreeInfo | 
       .rootProjectChildren[] | .nm as $h2 | 
       .ch[] | select(.ch != null) |
       .ch[] | select(.nm == $filter) | $h2')

echo "$data"
```

Note that `==` is exact match, if you need contains you can use :

```
select(.nm | contains($filter))
```

Comment: Thanks  Not sure how to use the $var bit? echo "$h2" shows nothing

Comment: `$h2` var is internal to jq, you can't use it outside. I've updated the answer to get the result in an external variable

Comment: does not seem to find all ids

Comment: ADM-F01
ADM-F01.1
ADM-F01.2
ADM-F01.3
ADM-F01.4
ADM-F02
ADM-F02.1
ADM-F02.2
ADM-F02.3
ADM-F02.4
ADM-F10
ADM-F10.1
ADM-F10.2
ADM-F10.3
ADM-F20
ADM-F20.1
ADM-F20.2
ADM-F20.3
ADM-F20.4
ADM-F31
ADM-F31.1
ADM-F31.2
ADM-F31.3
ADM-F31.4
ADM-F31.5
ADM-F32
ADM-F32.1
ADM-F32.2
ADM-F32.3
ADM-F32.4
ADM-F33
ADM-F33.1

Comment: Searched using some of the above but not all found